# Mongo $push is adding 2 array elements when it should only being adding 1

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using Mongo v4.4.3 and Node.js

I have a Mongo document like:

```
{
    "_id": "6060f7a3ff557c7a21b99d1f",
    "user": "3b0939b6-93e9-4ba8-b183-82819cf99999",
    "name": "Max Headroom",
    "gender": "M",
    "age": "28",
    "country": "Cameroon",
    "region": "Adamaoua",
    "questions": [
        {
            "_id": "6060f7a3ff557c7a21b99d20",
            "topics": [
                {
                    "_id": "6060f7a3ff557c7a21b99d21",
                    "topic": "Malaria"
                }
            ],
            "keepPrivate": false,
            "validQuestion": true,
            "question": "1st test question to see if it will be added",
            "askedAt": "2021-03-08T22:15:10.123Z"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

I have node.js code to update the name/age and add a new question using:

```
async function updateExistingUserAndAddQuestion(userQuestion, res){
    // The user under the uuid exists so update all the user fields and add the
    // question to the questions array
     newQuestion = userQuestion.questions[0]
     await Users.updateOne({"user" : userQuestion.user}
          ,{$set : {name : userQuestion.name
          ,age : userQuestion.age
          ,$push: {questions: {$each:[newQuestion], $position: -0 }}
          }
          , function(err , results){
                   if (err) {
                       errorResult(err,res)
                   } else {
                       return res.status(200).send(results)
                   }
            }
     );
}
```

But when I update the existing document, changing the age and adding a new question:

```
{
      "user": "3b0939b6-93e9-4ba8-b183-82819cf99999",
      "name": "Max Headroom",
      "age": "31",
      "questions": [
         {
            "topics": [{"topic":  "Malaria" }],
            "keepPrivate" : false,
            "validQuestion" : true,
            "question": "2nd test question to see if it will be added",
            "askedAt": "2021-03-10T06:02:03.456"
          }
      ]
}
```

I end up with the new question being added twice.

```
{
    "_id": "6060f7a3ff557c7a21b99d1f",
    "user": "3b0939b6-93e9-4ba8-b183-82819cf99999",
    "name": "Max Headroom",
    "age": "30",
    "questions": [
        {
            "_id": "6060f8faff557c7a21b99d23",
            "topics": [
                {
                    "_id": "6060f8faff557c7a21b99d24",
                    "topic": "Malaria"
                }
            ],
            "keepPrivate": false,
            "validQuestion": true,
            "question": "2nd test question to see if it will be added",
            "askedAt": "2021-03-10T06:02:03.456Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "6060f8faff557c7a21b99d23",
            "topics": [
                {
                    "_id": "6060f8faff557c7a21b99d24",
                    "topic": "Malaria"
                }
            ],
            "keepPrivate": false,
            "validQuestion": true,
            "question": "2nd test question to see if it will be added",
            "askedAt": "2021-03-10T06:02:03.456Z"
        },
        {
            "_id": "6060f7a3ff557c7a21b99d20",
            "topics": [
                {
                    "_id": "6060f7a3ff557c7a21b99d21",
                    "topic": "Malaria"
                }
            ],
            "keepPrivate": false,
            "validQuestion": true,
            "question": "1st test question to see if it will be added",
            "askedAt": "2021-03-08T22:15:10.123Z"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

What do I need to do to get Mongo to only add the new question once?

Comment: Your `$set` and `$push` usage looks syntactically wrong (thats not the reason for adding two array elements, I think).

Comment: I found if I remove the async from the function call and await from the mongo updateOne command I get the correct result.  Any ideas why that is?

Comment: I am not sure - but I see you are mixing _callbacks_ and _promises_ in your code. I have seen its not a good idea to work like that. See [Promises and Callbacks](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/promises/).

Comment: Regarding the $set and $push syntax. I tried a bunch of variations to try to figure out what I was doing wrong. So the version above may not be the best. It was just where I left off out of frustration.

Comment: Thanks for the Promises and Callbacks link.  I am new to node.js and mongo.  I can't say they info has all sunk in yet, but it helps!